# jQuery - Parse JSON from multiple urls and append to multiple divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, json

I got a HTML list with 4 items (each item has their own id assigned). For each item in list, I'm trying to get JSON data from multiple urls using ajax, then parse the data to the item's id.

Expected result: Each item gets the JSON data, then it displays the output inside its div element.

Actual result: Only one of the items are able to display the JSON data.

**CODE:**

```js
$(window).bind("load", () => {

    const urls = ["http://35.187.8.168:88", "http://35.187.8.168:89"];
    const ids = ["#serv1_players", "#serv2_players", "#serv3_players", "#serv4_players"];
    $.ajax({
        url: urls.pop(),
        dataType: "text",
        success: function (data) {
            var json = $.parseJSON(data);
            $(ids.pop()).html(json.current_players + " players");
        }
    });

});
```

```css
.worlds-panel {
background-color: rgba(3, 155, 229, .37);
width: 184px;
margin: 2px;
border-radius: 10px;
padding: 5px 15px
}
ul.worlds-dropdown .selected, ul.worlds-dropdown li:hover {
background-color: rgba(16, 246, 136, .47);
width: 164px;
color: #fff;
}

ul.worlds-dropdown {
padding: 0;
margin: 0 0 0 -5px;
list-style-type: none
}

ul.worlds-dropdown li {
padding: 8px 16px;
border-radius: 6px;
line-height: 1.429;
-webkit-transition: .25s;
transition: .25s
}

ul.worlds-dropdown img {
display: block;
position: absolute;
width: 24px;
height: 24px;
margin-top: 4px
}

.worlds-text {
margin-left: 35px;
margin-top: 2px;
color: #fff
}

.tag {
margin-left: 123px;
position: absolute;
margin-top: -28px;
border-radius: 4px;
font-size: .65rem;
padding: 2px 4px;
text-align: center;
color: #fff;
background-color: #0091ea;
font-family: Ubuntu
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="worlds-panel">
<ul class="worlds-dropdown">
    <li onclick="setserver('35.187.8.168:443');">
        <img src="resource/images/ffa.png">
        <div class="worlds-text">FFA</div>
        <div class="tag" id="serv1_players"></div>
    </li>
    <li onclick="setserver('35.187.8.168:444');" id="worldsDefault">
        <img src="resource/images/ffa.png">
        <div class="worlds-text">Instant</div>
        <div class="tag" id="serv2_players"></div>
    </li>
    <li onclick="setserver('35.187.8.168:445');">
        <img src="resource/images/ffa.png">
        <div class="worlds-text">Instant 2</div>
        <div class="tag" id="serv3_players"></div>
    </li>
    <li onclick="setserver('35.187.8.168:446');">
        <img src="resource/images/ffa.png">
        <div class="worlds-text">Minions</div>
        <div class="tag" id="serv4_players"></div>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: "List of items" + "each item" = `for` loop

Comment: [MDN: Loops and iteration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop through your urls, and make an AJAX call to each one.

try this:

```
$(window).bind("load", () => {
    const arr = [
        { id: 0, url: "http://35.187.8.168:88", container: "#serv1_players" },
        { id: 1, url: "http://35.187.8.168:89", container: "#serv2_players" },
        { id: 2, url: "http://35.187.8.168:90", container: "#serv3_players" },
        { id: 3, url: "http://35.187.8.168:91", container: "#serv4_players" }
    ];

    $.each(arr, function (index, obj) {
        $.ajax({
            url: obj.url,
            dataType: "text",
            success: function (data) {
                var json = $.parseJSON(data);
                $(this.container).html(json.current_players + " players");
            }.bind(obj)
        });
     });
});
```

Comment: That works, however, it seems that the items is not sorted. They display randomly, as you can see here: http://35.187.8.168:89/

Comment: Because currently it depends on which ajax call returns first (because you use pop).
I would use an array of JSON objects, { id: 0, url: 'http://35.187.8.168:88', container: '#serv1_players' }, in order to fix this.
Then you can loop through this array with while or for loop and use the AJAX call.

Comment: Assuming I want to return everything in one ajax call, what would be the most efficient way of doing this, performance wise speaking?

Comment: AJAX call can get only one url as an input, so you will have to loop through your array.
A nicer way to do this would be maybe using $.each(urls, function (index, object) { // Do ajax call here and use the object from my previous comment })

Comment: Can you provide a snippet of this approach? Much appreciated

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139076/discussion-between-androidgl-and-matansh).